# Set environment in Groovy scripts, inside Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins settings I've added the `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` in system settings.

But if I run this code in the Groovy console:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

here is the result:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

How can I set the `PATH` variable also in Groovy scripts?

Comment: Could you print hostname in groovy script? how are you running the groovy script?  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/ `withEnv` provides one option.

Comment: I'm running Groovy from the Jenkins script console.  `['hostname'].execute().text` provides me the right hostname.